# Neo4j how to create multiple relationship with single Node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Right now i am creating One to One relation with following Cypher query

```
@Query("MATCH (R:`User`{uuid:{uuid}}), (L:`Role`{uuid:{roleUuid}}) CREATE (R)-[r:`FILTER_ON`]->(L);")
```

Now my issue i have multiple `roleUuid` like `roleUuid1`,`roleUuid2`,`roleUuid3` etc now i want to create a relationship with User(`uuid`) with multiple `roleUuid`

How it can be done in Cypher query?

Answer (score 1):

Using a parameter `roleUuids` containing a list of role UUIDs, you can issue

```
MATCH (R:`User`{uuid:{uuid}}), (L:`Role`)
WHERE L.uuid IN {roleUuids}
CREATE (R)-[r:`FILTER_ON`]->(L)
```

or if you have an index on the `uuid` property:

```
UNWIND {roleUuids} AS roleUuid
MATCH (R:`User`{uuid:{uuid}}), (L:`Role`{uuid:roleUuid})
CREATE (R)-[r:`FILTER_ON`]->(L)
```

One remark: if you're on recent Neo4j versions, I'd suggest using the `$parameter` syntax instead of the `{parameter}` one to improve readability.

Comment: With `IN` if we can achieve this why to use `Index`?

Comment: If you created the indices, the performance of the second variant will be significantly better. Depending on the size of your database, this might not make much of a difference - if you only have a few thousand nodes, a vanilla (no-index) database will work fine.

Comment: SO `IN' will make multiple relationship with Single Node in one go right?

Comment: One more thing `roleUuid` in my case is a list so it should not create any issue.

Comment: "SO `IN' will make multiple relationship with Single Node in one go right?" The two solutions in the answer are identical. Both will create multiple relationships using a single query.

Comment: "One more thing roleUuid in my case is a list so it should not create any issue." In this case, the parameter `roleUuids` will be a list of lists. That's fine and works correctly because you can [index a full array](https://community.neo4j.com/t/multi-valued-field-indexing/3873/3).

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas Actually, indexing can work with both of your queries. Also, your second query should have its `WHERE` clause removed since it is unnecessary.

Comment: `WHERE L.uuid IN {roleUuids}` this is proper or we have to add `[]`